# Limit of ratio of polynomials, without L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: limits

> Evaluate the following limit. (*L’Hopital’s* rule is not allowed.)
>   $$\lim \limits_{x\to -\frac 12}  \frac{4x^3 − 3x − 1}{4x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 4x + 1}$$

What does it mean by *L'Hopital's* Rule is not allowed? So do I just sub in $x \to-\frac 12$ into the equation to find the limit directly? I have no idea how to tackle this question. Is there any other way beside direct sub?

Comment: You cannot directly substitute, because doing so will get you a $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form. Haven't you been taught before L'Hopital the techniques to tackle indeterminate forms?

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{4x^3-3x-1}{4x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 4x + 1}\;\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$$ form

So we will use Factorisation Method

So Put $\displaystyle x=-\frac{1}{2}\;,$ we get  $4x^3-3x-1=0$. So using factor theorem $\displaystyle x=-\frac{1}{2}\;$

is a factor of  $4x^3-3x-1=0$. Similarly for $4x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 4x + 1$

So $4x^3-3x-1 = (x-1)(2x+1)^2$ and $4x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 4x + 1 = (2x+1)^2\cdot (x^2+1)$

So we get $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{(x-1)(2x+1)^2}{(x^2+1)(2x+1)^2} =\lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}=-\frac{3}{2}\times \frac{4}{5} =-\frac{6}{5}$$

Evaluation of limit Using $\bf{L\; Hopital\; Rule}$ Given $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{4x^3-3x-1}{4x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 4x + 1}$$

So we get $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{12x^2-3}{16x^3+12x^2+10x+4}$

again using , We get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}}\frac{24x}{48x^2+24x+10} = -\frac{6}{5}$$

Comment: The first and last line make for a complete answer. No idea what you are doing in the four lines inbetween.

Comment: so if L'hopital's rule is allowed then how to solve it with the rule?

Comment: To user271716 I have edited my post.